# How to include "s" if it is exist in matching word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get all matches of both the singular and plural of a word with JavaScript and regex.

For example, if I were to match the word `"plumber"`, I'd want to return all matches of both `"plumber"` and `"plumbers"`.

The code that I use is:

```js
var re = new RegExp(`${[[plumber]]}\\b`);

if ([[SOME TEXT]].match(re)) {
```

Comment: Did you try? `new RegExp(\`\b${"plumber"}(\w*)?\b\`)` or simply `/\bplumber(\w*)?\b/`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `?` in your regex. There's a good write-up on what it means [here](https://dh.obdurodon.org/regex-tips.xhtml)

> A question mark (?) immediately following a character means "match zero or one instance of this character"

You'll also want to use [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to get all occurrences of the string.

```js
let re = /plumbers?/g;
let plumbersString = 'plumbers plumb plumbingly, plumber plumb plumber';

for(match of plumbersString.matchAll(re)) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have this code:
if ([[ELEMENT]].match([[plumber]])){
var re = new RegExp(`${[[plumber]]}\\b`);
if([[ELEMENT]].match(re)){
[[KW_HTML]] = [

```
                        "<a title=\"Learn More About [cn]'s " + [[plumber]] + " in [ln]\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"" + [[plumber]] + " in [ln]\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"Learn More About [cn]'s " + [[plumber]] + "\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"More About [cn]'s " +[[plumber]] + "\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"More About [cn]'s " +[[plumber]] + " in [ln]\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]]  + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"About [cn]'s " +[[plumber]] + "\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>",
                            "<a title=\"About [cn]'s " +[[plumber]] + " in [ln]\" href=\"/\">" + [[plumber]] + "</a>"
                ]
                [[KW_HTML]] = [[KW_HTML]][(Math.random() * [[KW_HTML]].length) | 0]
                if([[HTML_TAG]] == "false"){
                    [[ELEMENT]] = [[ELEMENT]].replace([[plumber]], [[KW_HTML]])
                    [[KWIF]].push("vleze v KW na zavurtane #"+[[I]] )
                    [[HTML_TAG]] = "true"
                }        
            } 
        }
```

and word in text is "plumbers" i want to add "s" in some of KW_HTML..Now it looks like that for example:

```
<a title="More About [cn]'s plumber in [ln]" href="/">plumber</a>s
```

Comment: <a title="More About [cn]'s plumber in [ln]" href="/">plumber</a>s THIS MUST LOOK LIKE THAT: <a title="More About [cn]'s plumbers in [ln]" href="/">plumbers</a>